# the application has stopped unexpectdly

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to android and developing an application that uses the google maps API.

while running the application I have the error :

> the application has stopped unexpectedly

Here's what I have in the logcat file :

```
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.training.surveyproject/com.training.surveyproject.SurveyActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.training.surveyproject.SurveyActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.training.surveyproject-2.apk]
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.training.surveyproject.SurveyActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.training.surveyproject-2.apk]
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
07-11 01:38:25.751: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  ... 11 more
```

thank you

Answer (score 3):

You must add the activity `SurveyActivity` to your AndroidManifest.xml file.

You may have also forgotten to add the Google Map Library to the manifest:

```
<application>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
```

Comment: thank u so much i was missing the library com.google.android.maps library in the manifest

Comment: @user1516388 Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept this answer if it works so anyone else with the same problem knows what to do.